# how add a UIscrollView in a view controller ??

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, addition

I have a view controller  .h and .m and I don't know how 
to add it to .xib
I pick a UIScrollView and I put it in the view of the .xib

but I can not relie his outlet to the declared UIScrollView in the viewController.h

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to follow what you're trying to do.  So you have presumably defined your UIScrollView in your header file as such:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

And now you need to link that to your XIB file?  If you open the XIB file and click your main window of that view so the outside of it is selected, then you'll get properties available to you on the right hand side of your Xcode project.  On the third tab the first field contains a place for you to select the UIViewController class you defined that UIScrollView.  Select it.  Then you can click+drag from your window to the UIScrollView in your XIB to connect it.

Comment: I don't know why but I still can not relie it

Comment: in the end it work I declare mu UiScrollView on a UIView and I relie it know it doesn't show it in the view ,did I miss something !!!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're missing I guess.  Can you describe the steps you took and what failed or didn't go right?

Comment: in fact it was my fault :s I don't pay attention thinks